# How to find a window with known lpClassName but multilingual lpWindowName

Tags: c#

I'm trying to find the sound control panel window via [FindWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499(v=vs.85).aspx). Since the application is used in multiple languages lpWindowName changes for example "Sound" becomes "Ääni" on a Finnish system. However the lpClassName stays the same.

```
        // Get a handle to an application window.
        [DllImport("USER32.DLL", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName,
        string lpWindowName);

        //  The window class and window name
        //  were obtained using the Spy++ tool.
        IntPtr soundHandle = FindWindow("#32770", "Sound");

        // Verify that Sound is a running process.
        if (soundHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Sound is not running.");
            return;
        }
```

I have searched and cannot find a way to grab a window based upon it's lpClassName alone. I believe this is because it can change for most windows, this doesn't seem to be the case for Sound control panel.

Is there a way around the lpWindowName changing on different language systems?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: My apologies. I thought it would be showing I made an attempt at a solution rather than falling foul of XY. Edited original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trouble is, multiple windows may share the same class name. `FindWindow()` filters windows based on class name.

You might consider using: `EnumWindows()` and enumerate all instances of your window class yourself. Careful, there may be more than one.